# Express + Multer without redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, multer

I wrote a code that upload a file to server. But, just after the upload finish the system redirect me to the upload route. How can I upload a file and stay in the first page?

For example:

```
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
  });    
});
```

When the upload finish, I am redirected to localhost:3000/upload. I don't want it. I want to stay in localhost:3000 and in my current session.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the request without the browser navigating to where the form is being submitted, then you may want to [use XHR and FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) in one way or another to submit the form request instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fine here!