# How upload a file with express/multer without redirecting

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, multer

Note: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846303/express-multer-without-redirect#) post, but I didn't find helpful, and other posts are related to angular/react, which I am not using.

I have a file upload that should send a response that the file is of the correct type. The file upload works correctly, but my page redirects to where the file is located. I'd like the page to same on the same page where it was located.

home.ejs:

```
<!-- upload video -->
<form method="post" action="/upload" class="custom-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="video-file" class="custom-file-input" />
  <span class="custom-file-control"></span>

  <!-- optional dropdown to specify number of cores -->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
            type="button" 
            id="dropdownMenuButton" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            aria-expanded="false"
            name="number-of-cores">
      Use all Cores
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item">Use all Cores</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Use one Core</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- upload button -->
  <input class="btn btn-primary upload-btn" type="submit" id="upload-btn" value="Upload">
```

This is the reason I want the page to not redirect; so the page can display if the file is of the correct format or not.

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload-btn', function (event) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/',
          dataType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          contentType: JSON.stringify(false),
          success: function (response) { 
              $("#errorMessage").html("* file successfully opened");
              console.log('successfully uploaded', response);
          },
          error: function (result) {
              $("#errorMessage").html("* Incorrect file/no file given");
              console.log('coudn\'t upload');
          }
      });
      //return false;
  })
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path')

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');
app.use(express.static('public'));

function fileFilter (req, file, cb) {
    if (path.extname(file.originalname) !== '.mp4') {
        return cb(null, false);
    }

    cb(null, true);
}

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/', fileFilter:fileFilter});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', { testGreeting: 'Hello world' });
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('video-file'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.params);
    if (req.file) {
        console.log("successfully received");
        res.send({success: "success"});
    }
    return res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on Port 3000.'));
```

This might be off topic, but my ajax code always runs the error, and never the success. If I could get help with that too, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

UPDATE: `event.preventDefault()` was the solution:

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload-btn', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
              ... //same as before
      });
      return false;
})
```

Comment: try `res.redirect('/')` instead of `res.end()` in app.post/upload

Comment: Why have you commented out `return false;`? What happens when it is uncommented?

Comment: @YasserHussain I tried it and nothing happened as far as I can tell. At the very least, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Did you try `event.preventDefault`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent default browser action with `event.preventDefault()` on clientside. You can learn more about preventDefault [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)